# React - problems with useState and Firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, functional-programming, react-hooks

I was trying to resolve this problem, but I have no luck...

I'm using React and 'react-bootstrap'. Getting data from firebase with `useState`, as you can see in the next code. But also I'm calling a modal as a component, and this modal use `useState` to show and hide the modal.

```
export const Models = () => {

    const [models, setModels] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        firebase.database().ref('Models').on('value', (snapshot) => {
            setModels(snapshot.val())
        });

    }, []);
    return models;
}
```

the problem result when I click on the url to access the modal, this one is shown and the main component goes to firebase and tries to get the data again. So, if I click 3 times on the modal, I will get my data from firebase 3 times.

How can I fix this? to get my data from firebase only one time, regardless of the times that you open the modal window?

The other part of the code

```
const Gallery = () => {

    const [fireBaseDate, setFireBaseDate] = useState(null);
    axios.post('https://us-central1-models-gallery-puq.cloudfunctions.net/date',{format:'DD/MM/YYYY'})
    .then((response) => {
        setFireBaseDate(response.data)
    });

    let content = Models();
    let models = [];

    const [imageModalShow, setImageModalShow] = useState(false);
    const [selectedModel, setSelectedModel] = useState('');


    if(content){
        Object.keys(content).map((key, index) => 
        models[index] = content[key]
        );

        models = shuffleArray(models);
        console.log(models)

        return(
            <div className="appContentBody">
                <Jumbo />
                <Promotion models={models}/>
                <div className="Gallery">
                <h1>Galería - Under Patagonia</h1>

                <Filter />

                <div className="img-area">
                    {models.map((model, key) =>{
                        let myDate = new Date(model.creationDate);
                        let modelEndDate = new Date(myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate() + 30)).toLocaleDateString('en-GB')
                        if(fireBaseDate !== modelEndDate && model.active === true){
                            return (
                                <div className="img-card filterCard" key={key}>
                                    <div className="flip-img">
                                        <div className="flip-img-inner">
                                            <div className="flip-img-front">
                                                <img className="single-img card-img-top" src={model.thumbnail} alt="Model"/>
                                            </div>
                                            <div className="flip-img-back">
                                                <h2>{model.certified ? 'Verificada!' : 'No Verificada'}</h2>
                                                <p>Número: {model.contact_number}</p>
                                                <p>Ciudad: {model.city}</p>
                                                <p>Servicios: {model.services}</p>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <h5>{model.name}</h5>

                                    <Button variant="danger" onClick={() => {
                                                setImageModalShow(true)
                                                setSelectedModel(model)}
                                                }>
                                        Ver
                                    </Button>
                                </div>  
                            );
                        }
                    return 0})}                
                </div>
                    <Image
                        show={imageModalShow}
                        onHide={() => setImageModalShow(false)}
                        model={selectedModel}
                    />
                </div>
            <Footer />
            </div>
    )} else {
        return (
            <div className="loading">
                <h1>Loading...</h1>
            </div>
    )}
}


export default Gallery;
```

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Models is a regular javascript function, not a functional component. So this is not a valid use of hooks, and will not work as expected. See docs on [rules of hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html).

A functional component receives props and returns JSX or another React element.

Since it does not, it is basically restarting and calling your effect each time its called by the parent.

Looking at your edit, you should probably just remove the `Models` function and put the logic in the `Gallery` component.

Answer (score 0):

The way I read your above component makes it seem like you've defined a custom hook for getting data from firebase.

So first off, I would rename it to useFbData and treat it as a custom hook, so that you can make use of the [ESLint Plugin for Hooks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-react-hooks) and make sure you're following the [rules of hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html).

The way you have this above, if it's a function within a component, your function will fire on every render, so the behaviour you are describing is what I would expect.

Depending on how expensive your request is/how often that component renders, this might be what you want, as you probably don't want to return stale data to your component. However, if you feel like the response from the DB should be cached and you have some logic to invalidate that data you could try something like this:

```
import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

const useFbData = invalidationFlag => {
  const data = useRef(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!data.current || invalidationFlag) {
      firebase.database().ref('Data').on('value', (snapshot) => {
        data.current = snapshot.val();
      });
    }
  }, [invalidationFlag]);
  return data.current;
};

export default useFbData;
```

This way, on the initial run and every time you changed the value of invalidationFlag, your effect inside the useFbData hook would run. Provided you keep track of invalidationFlag and set it as required, this could work out for you.

The reason I used a ref here instead of state, is so that the effect hook doesn't take the data in the dependency array (which would cause it to loop indefinitely if we used state).

This will persist the result of the db response between each call and prevent the call being made multiple times until you invalidate. Remember though, this will mean the data you're using is stale until you invalidate.